# My home air conditioner that's inside the house, seems to be sputtering when coming on. What could this be?

Tags: hvac

My home air conditioner inside the house; when it's going thru its normal cycle of off and on, it seems to be sputtering and/or hesitating to come on. It's like or similar to a car that having a hard time staying running. Once it's doing this, it eventually stays on and is still cooling the house. The fan outside is fine and we don't hear any other noises. Please help soon as possible.

Comment: If it's a blower making the noise it may need a new capacitor.  This is hard to diagnose without more details.

Comment: What's the make and model of the unit?  Can you record the sound, post it somewhere on the internet, and provide a link to it here?

Answer (score -1):

If it sounds like liquid than I'd guess that the pump that circulates the coolant isn't being submerged properly when in its sleep state, and only once it gets a good vacuum and liquid pouring into its reservoir does it quiet down. I'd have someone check the fluid levels as you may need more of whatever coolant (Freon?) it uses.